# Как избежать дублирование в AJAX запросе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть ли возможность избежать дублирование в AJAX запросе

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input.ajax-post_company',function(){
NProgress.start();
event.preventDefault();

var company_id = $('#company_id').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/c/create/'+ company_id +'/update',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: {
        title: $('#title').val(),   
        slug: $('#slug').val(),
        vk_link: $('#vk_link').val(),
        insta_link: $('#insta_link').val(),
        youtube_link: $('#youtube_link').val(),
        fb_link: $('#fb_link').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        city_phone: $('#city_phone').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        site: $('#site').val(),
        yandex_map: $('#yandex_map').val(),
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert( "Страница не найдена." );
        }
    },
    success: function(result){
        // if (result.notify) {
        //  $('#notify').append('<div class="notify_block">'+ result.notify +'</div>');             
        //  setTimeout(function() {
        //      hideNotify();
        //  }, 5000);
        // }
        NProgress.done();
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        NProgress.done();
    }
})
});
```

Чтоб не дублировать постоянно

```
        title: $('#title').val(),   
        slug: $('#slug').val(),
        vk_link: $('#vk_link').val(),
        insta_link: $('#insta_link').val(),
        youtube_link: $('#youtube_link').val(),
        fb_link: $('#fb_link').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        city_phone: $('#city_phone').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        site: $('#site').val(),
        yandex_map: $('#yandex_map').val(),
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {};
$("common_parent_selector").find("input,select,textarea").each(function(){
  data[this.id] = this.value;
});
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: data,
  ...
```